# Turn on Flashlight on Motorola XYBoard

Tags: android, android-camera

I am writing an app to turn on the flashlight for a fixed duration on my Motorola XYBoard . Below is my piece of code , While this code works on Motorola Attrix and Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 its not working on the XYBoard.  I did check the supported flash modes and torch is one of them . I have read multiple discussions on stack overflow where others faced a similar problem but nothing that I tried worked. Would be really helpful if someone to help me out

public void flashLightOn() {

```
    try {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {

            cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            List<String> abc = p.getSupportedFlashModes();

            for (String a : abc){
                Log.d("mode: ", a);
    }
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
           /* cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                }
            });*/

        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception flashLightOn()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void flashLightOff() {
    try {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception flashLightOff",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install one of the torchlight app from the App store and your app will just invoke the app using an intent.

This way less coding!

Comment: That is a good idea but unfortunately I need to develop something of my own .